# How do you change the text color of a readonly TextBox?

Tags: c#

I am writing a dictionary with c# and I'm using a textbox to show the definitions.  Obviously, I need to set the ReadOnly property to true, but when I do that I'm unable to change the color of the text.  Changing the Font however works fine.  What should I do?

I'm using this code and setting the color works perfectly fine when the ReadOnly property is false, but doesn't change when it is true:

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FontDialog fd = new FontDialog();
        fd.ShowColor = true;
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox3.Font = fd.Font;
            textBox3.ForeColor = fd.Color;
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried setting it to .enabled = false?

Comment: If i disable it the scroll wont work. so there is no use :/

Comment: This is actually documented on MSDN (that the color doesn't change on a ReadOnly control).  But the workaround (your accepted answer) is not documented ... except here.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The ForeColor property of a read-only TextBox is married to the BackColor property for some reason.  So if you "tickle" the BackColor property, it will set the ForeColor property after that:

```
FontDialog fd = new FontDialog();
fd.ShowColor = true;
if (fd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
  textBox3.Font = fd.Font;
  textBox3.BackColor = textBox3.BackColor;
  textBox3.ForeColor = fd.Color;
}
```

Comment: Well all be jiggered. That's a sensible architecture. Ugh.

Comment: Holy obscurity, Batman!  That's non-obvious! (Oddly, this isn't necessary for `ResetForeColor`.)

Comment: @Rajiv Lots and lots of experience where you just end up noticing these things.

Comment: Now, that's super weird!

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the ForeColor is already set to the desired color (possibly in the designer), all that needs to be done is:

```
tb.BackColor = tb.BackColor;
```

This will magically trigger and fix the fore color. Although a comment explaining why this line of code is added is probably also needed.

Comment: Weird, but true in .NET 4.52.

Comment: Still true in .NET 4.8

Answer (score 4):

In VS 2017 this is not even needed.

In designer if you have set your ForeColor and BackColor as desired and want to switch ReadOnly on your TextBox to True

- Change BackColor to any random color and compile
- Change BackColor to your desired color and compile

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to LarsTech suggestion I had to set the back color and then set it again

This is the method that worked for me:

```
    tb.BackColor = Color.Black
    tb.ForeColor = Color.Black
    tb.BackColor = Color.White
```